# "add_query_arg" and SEO

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I use `add_query_arg` to pass a variable from one page to another:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'country', $c, get_permalink(14) ) ); ?>">Contact</a>
```

That gives me this type of URL:

```
http://www.example.com/contact?country=france
http://www.example.com/contact?country=england
http://www.example.com/contact?country=spain
```

This information should be only for me (a prefilled `select` field on the form) and not for users (especially for the Google bots).

I would like to hide `?country=value` to get the final URL:

```
http://www.example.com/contact
```

How can I do? (I guess I have to edit the `.htaccess`, but I do not understand this language.)

Unless there was another way to send directly hidden `variables?`

Comment: I think you have to use `$_POST` or you could ask google to ignore `?country` parameter. (The latter can be done by going to webmaster tools)

Comment: `$_POST` can only be used for forms, is not it? (I use a href link)
In Webmaster Tools,  it just allows you to ignore, I would hide it completely for users too.

Comment: Yeah, but that is a way, where you can hide the parameter The second one would be to pass through cookies

Comment: You can't have one URL going to different pages, even if the differences are subtle … and you're being way too paranoid about duplicate content algorithms in search engines.

Comment: No solution with `.htaccess`?